# Scheduled cronjob triggered by PHP script

Tags: cron

My goal is simple: if a visitor reaches a particular PHP page, and gives me her e-mail address, then **two hours later** I send her an email.

To sum it up: how can I delay a task after a script has been hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and probably the most error prone way is to store the list of "times to send" and emails which is handled by a system cron. Depending on how much precise the timing must be and how many users you are serving, you might chose the cron repeat time of a one minute or more.

Comment: so the cron would regularly run a PHP script that would check the email queue and send the queued one? good idea I must say, it is kind of the PULL approach; I would be curious to read a PULL one.

Comment: It's pretty hard to go the other way. Also, compared to many postponed processes waiting two hours, I'd say it's also better performance-wise.